# Google Analytics tagging

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have the current code to track the % of a scroll on a page.

```
ga('create', 'UA-68653010-1', 'auto');
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  var viewportHeight = $(this).height();
  var progress = $(this).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - viewportHeight);
  ga('send', 'event', 'scroll', Math.round(progress*100));
};
```

But whenever the event should send the hit it returns a different than the expected, which one of the Parameters is:

> exd:ReferenceError: ga is not defined

Comment: Did you include the code that loads the analytics.js library ? One of the parameters is the name of the global tracker function, if you passed anything in instead of "ga" then your tracker function will not ne defined and you need to change the name accordingly.

Comment: The problem was right there! But somehow when I ran the code on Console the hits were sending normally, it just didn't worked when I placed the code on my tagmanager. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include your JS-files (fragments) in the right sequence.

Include this script first:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)
[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-68653010-1', 'auto') ; 
</script>
```

...
Then include your main JS-file which contains `onbeforeunload` handler:

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
      var viewportHeight = $(this).height();
      var progress = $(this).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - viewportHeight);
      ga('send', 'event', 'scroll', Math.round(progress*100));
};
```